# Return maximum length of the sequence of same items within array

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function called `countZeroes`, which accepts an array of only `0s` and `1s`.

The function should return the longest number of 1s in a row.

```
countZeroes([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]) // 2
countZeroes([1,1,1,1,0,1]) // 4
```

This is what I currently have.

```
function countZeros(arr){
  total = 0 
  for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] ===1)
      total += 1
    }
    return total
  
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I know I need to compare the right index and the left index. I tried using a nested for loop which didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset `total` to zero when a 0 occur and keep track of the `max` number of repeated 1s:

```js
function countZeros(arr){
  total = 0, max = 0;
  for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] === 1){
      total += 1;
      if(total>max)
        max = total;
    }else{
      total = 0;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(countZeros([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]));
console.log(countZeros([1,1,1,1,0,1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function countZeros(arr){
  let longest = 0;  // Initialize longest (0)
  let total = 0;  // Initialize total (0)
  for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    if( arr[i] ===1 ) // If 1, increment total
      total += 1
    if( total > longest ) // If the total so far is longer than longest, save it.
      longest = total;
    if( arr[i] !== 1 ) // If not 1, reset total; AFTER conditionally saving it.
      total = 0;
  }
  return longest; // Return longest found
}

console.log( countZeros([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]) ); // 2
console.log( countZeros([1,1,1,1,0,1]) ); // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join your array and split it using `0` as separator. Resulting array of successive `1` is then sorted from shortest to longest. You can finally get the last item of array using `pop()`:

```js
const countZeroes = (arr) => arr.join('').split(0).sort().pop().length

console.log(countZeroes([1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]))
console.log(countZeroes([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]))
```

Comment: While it is compact, it may be [way too slow](https://jsbench.me/9ikc9jk1z0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
function countZeroes(arr) {
  let max = 0;
  let current = 0;
  for(let i=0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == 1) {
      ++current;
    }
    else {  // arr[i] == 0
      if (current > max) max = current;
      current = 0
    }
  }
  if (current > max) max = current;
  return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the longest combination of 1s.

```
[1,1,1,1,0,1].toString().replace(/,/gi, "").split("0").sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0].length
```

Comment: This answer alone is useless for a beginner without explanation. You should explain what you do.

Comment: Sorting and regexing are all pretty expensive operations and may [cost you a lot of CPU cycles](https://jsbench.me/9ikc9jk1z0/1) where single pass over the source array is pretty much [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62745982/11299053)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach and counter

```js
g={}
function countZeroes(arr){
 var  count;
  arr.forEach((x,i)=>{
    count=g[x]||1
    if(x==1&&arr[i-1]==1) {g[x]=count+1}
  })
  g={}
  return count 
}
 console.log(countZeroes([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1])) // 2
 console.log(countZeroes([1,1,1,1,0,1]));
console.log(countZeroes([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with array methods.

```js
function count_longest_sequence_of_ones(array){
  return array
    .reduce( count_sequential_ones, [0])
    .sort()
    .pop();
  
  function count_sequential_ones(acc, number) {
    if( number === 1 ) acc[acc.length-1]++;
    else acc.push(0);
    return acc;
  }
}

console.log(count_longest_sequence_of_ones([0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]));
console.log(count_longest_sequence_of_ones([1,1,1,1,0,1]));
```

PS: Looks like you got plenty of answers :). Use the one you find easiest to understand.